# MSSQL: Date is greater than specific date or is null

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, isnull

This is so basic, i'm already sorry.

Where clause is: start date greater than 7/1/18 and end date is greater than 10/1/18 or is null

This where clause gets me what I need, but I'd rather use 'ISNULL' instead of OR.

```
WHERE l.[Start Date]  > '07/01/2018' and (l.[End Date] > '10/1/2018' or l.[End Date] is null)
```

Can I say:

```
WHERE l.[Start Date]  > '07/01/2018' and (l.[End Date] > ISNULL(l.[End Date]) or something?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `isnull()` you can do it like this:

```
WHERE l.[Start Date] > '07/01/2018' and isnull(l.[End Date], '11/1/2018') > '10/1/2018'
```

If `l.[End Date]` is `null` then

```
isnull(l.[End Date], '11/1/2018')
```

will return

```
'11/1/2018'
```

and the condition

```
isnull(l.[End Date], '11/1/2018') > '10/1/2018'
```

will return `true`. 
Of course you can use instead any date like `'1/1/2099'`

Comment: Thank you very much - I was unsure the syntax of where the > symbol would be with isnull. You rock.

Comment: @forpas, on the first code line, where you wrote 11/1/**218**, I believe you meant 11/1/**2018**. I can't edit it because it's only one character change.

Comment: @RichardII of course... Even after I read your comment, it took me a while to find it.. I'm getting old...